# MVC send Model with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I am having an issue when trying to send data back to my save method using ajax. I would like to do it this way because I am reusing the form in several screens by rendering it as a partial page with using the same save function.

The problem I am having is when I do it this way it does work and sends it back to my save function, but the serialized Json is made when the page loads and doesn't get the updated values. I would like to get the updated values sent back with ajax, ideally without having to capture the values of every field on my page.

Below is the code I am using now that does work for sending back to my save method with the original values listed in the Model

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    var form = $('#Form');

    if (form.valid()) {
        var data = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model))';

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Save",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ modelJson: data }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                SaveFade();
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: create a partial view and just have the json result return a partial view, then you can just update the whole div so you don't have to track all of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please use `.done`, `.fail`, and `.always` methods on Deferred which jQuery's `$.ajax` methods returns instead of `success`.
Secondly, do not use Razor methods directly in JavaScript, as single quote character `'` may cause syntax errors. Instead close this data in hidden `div` with id, for example:
`<div id="formData">@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model))</div>`, then in JavaScript do: `var data = $('#formData').html();`. This way you can also move your scripts into seperate .js file.

Answering your problem, you must send actual form using ajax to controller method. Close all fields in form, assign id for form `@using(Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))`, and send it using AJAX:

```
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        var form = $('#Form');

        if (form.valid()) {
            var data = form.serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Save", //you can get also action attribute from form using form.attr('action')
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            }).done(function (result) {
                SaveFade();
            });
         }

         return false;
     });
```

Good tutorial about forms in ASP.NET MVC: http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the .done over the success:. I was just using an old example I found kicking around.

I have tried the solution you proposed and it does send the correct data back now, but looking at the data it sends, it is sending it as a query string. What is the best way to parse this?